# How to input rpc text file in warp

Tags: raster, gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

How to input rpc text file in gdalwarp taransformation. I tought as follow

```
C:\Users\admin>gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -rpc input_rpc.txt  input.tif output.tif
```

Its giving error as input_rpc.txt not recognized as supported file format

Comment: You need to provide additional information. Why do you need to provide your RPCs as a textfile? How is the textfile formatted? What imagery are you working on?

Comment: I dnont know in wich other formats RPC's can be provided as inpurt, Presdently I'm working with Kompsat data, They are provided rpc in text file

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your approach with pointing at the RPC-file isn't supported by gdal, which is why you are getting the error message. If you read the documentation for gdalwarp, you'll notice that it doesn't expect to get a textfile for the RPCs, as it automatically tries to find the information. Try the same command, just without the input_rpc.txt element.

Comment: Please tell me the other way to input the rpc file or data.

Comment: GDAL should spot the RPCs automatically - you can test this by using gdalinfo. If GDAL doesn't see the information, you can try to rename your RPC-file to input.rpb

Comment: You are supposed to keep the metadata file in the same directory than the image. The kompsat metadata reader code should then know what to do https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/gcore/mdreader/reader_kompsat.cpp

Comment: I kept both image and rpc file in same folder

Comment: I tried by removing input_rpc.txt, It's giving the error
C:\Users\admin>gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -rpc input.tif out.tif
ERROR 1: Unable to compute a RPC based transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates for  input.tif

Comment: So what goes wrong if you do `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -rpc input.tif output.tif --debug on`? Or perhaps just `gdalwarp -rpc input.tif output.tif --debug on`. BTW have you read http://fwarmerdam.blogspot.fi/2013/09/exploring-rpcs.html?

Comment: C:\Users\admin>gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -rpc input.tif output.tif --debug on
GDAL: GDALOpen(input.tif, this=0000000002A26B60) succeeds as GTiff. ERROR 1: Unable to compute a RPC based transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates for input.tif.
GDAL: GDALClose(input.tif, this=0000000002A26B60)

Comment: What is your GDAL version? I believe you must have at least 2.0 for Kompsat metadata support. And of course, add to your question what `gdalinfo input.tif` shows for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57675/discussion-between-satya-chandra-and-user30184).